# Double integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{a-1}y^{b-1}}{(1+xy)\ln(xy)}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

Double integral   $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{a-1}y^{b-1}}{(1+xy)\ln(xy)}\,dx\,dy$$
$\displaystyle{a,b>0}$

## my work

$$I\left( {a,b} \right) = \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{x^a}{y^b}}}{{\ln \left( {xy} \right)}}dx\,dy} }  = \frac{{\ln \left( {\dfrac{{1 + b}}{{1 + a}}} \right)}}{{a-b}}$$

$$\displaystyle{I\left( {a,b} \right) = \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{x^a}{y^b}}}{{\ln \left( {xy} \right)}}dx\,dy} }  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {{x^a}{y^b}\left( { - \int\limits_0^\infty  {{e^{t \cdot \ln \left( {xy} \right)}}dt} } \right)dx\,dy} }  =  - \int\limits_0^\infty  {\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {{x^a}{y^b}{e^{t \cdot \ln \left( {xy} \right)}}dx\,dy} } } \right)dt}  =  - \int\limits_0^\infty  {\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {{x^a}{y^b}{{\left( {xy} \right)}^t}dx\,dy} } } \right)dt}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \int\limits_0^\infty  {\left( {\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {{x^{a + t}}dx} } \right)\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {{y^{b + t}}dy} } \right)} \right)dt}  =  - \int\limits_0^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{{a + 1 + t}} \cdot \frac{1}{{b + 1 + t}}} \right)dt}  = \frac{1}{{b - a}}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\left( { - \frac{1}{{a + 1 + t}} + \frac{1}{{b + 1 + t}}} \right)dt}  = \frac{{\ln \left( {\dfrac{{1 + b}}{{1 + a}}} \right)}}{{a - b}}}$$

$$\displaystyle{I = \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{x^{a - 1}}{y^{b - 1}}}}{{\left( {1 + xy} \right)\ln \left( {xy} \right)}}dx\,dy} }  = \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{x^{a - 1}}{y^{b - 1}}}}{{\ln \left( {xy} \right)}}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}{{\left( {xy} \right)}^k}} } \right)dx\,dy} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{x^{a + k - 1}}{y^{b + k - 1}}}}{{\ln \left( {xy} \right)}}dx\,dy} } } \right)} \right)} }$$

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Original question or where i am stuck?

Comment: I have computed, for positive $a,b$, that: $$I_{a,b}=\frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\cdot\ln\left(\frac{a+n}{b+n}\right)$$But I am not convinced there should be a closed form for this final series

Comment: If $a=b$ then the above is instead: $$I_{a,a}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\psi\left(\frac{a}{2}-1\right)-\psi\left(\frac{a-1}{2}\right)\right)$$But I forget my polygamma identities and am not sure if this admits a better closed form

Comment: James, do you expect a closed form? Is this part of some challenge question you found online, or did you just come up with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}$ by the double integral,

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(a,b\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{x^{a-1}y^{b-1}}{\left(1+xy\right)\ln{\left(xy\right)}};~~~\small{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}}.$$

Recalling the definition of the digamma function by

$$\psi{\left(z\right)}:=\frac{d}{dz}\ln{\left(\Gamma{\left(z\right)}\right)};~~~\small{\Re{(z)}>0}.$$

as well as its integral representation

$$\psi{\left(z\right)}=-\gamma+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1-t^{z-1}}{1-t};~~~\small{\Re{(z)}>0},$$

we obtain the following result for $\mathcal{I}$ in the $a\neq b$ case:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{x^{a-1}y^{b-1}}{\left(1+xy\right)\ln{\left(xy\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{x^{a-b}(xy)^{b-1}}{\left(1+xy\right)\ln{\left(xy\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{x^{a-b}u^{b-1}}{x\left(1+u\right)\ln{\left(u\right)}};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{u}{x}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{u}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{a-b-1}u^{b-1}}{\left(1+u\right)\ln{\left(u\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{b-1}}{\left(1+u\right)\ln{\left(u\right)}}\int_{u}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,x^{a-b-1}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{b-1}}{\left(1+u\right)\ln{\left(u\right)}}\cdot\frac{1-u^{a-b}}{a-b}\\
&=\frac{1}{a-b}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{b-1}-u^{a-1}}{\left(1+u\right)\ln{\left(u\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{a-b}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{1+u}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}t\,u^{t-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{a-b}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{t-1}}{1+u}\\
&=\frac{1}{a-b}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac12\left[\psi{\left(\frac{t+1}{2}\right)}-\psi{\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{a-b}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{d}{dt}\left[\ln{\left(\Gamma{\left(\frac{t+1}{2}\right)}\right)}-\ln{\left(\Gamma{\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{a-b}\left[\ln{\left(\Gamma{\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)}\right)}-\ln{\left(\Gamma{\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)}\right)}-\ln{\left(\Gamma{\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}\right)}+\ln{\left(\Gamma{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{a-b}\ln{\left(\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)}}\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

The $a=b$ case can be recovered from the above result using L'Hopital's rule to calculate the limit.

---

Comment: This is more than elegant

Comment: I am doubting the closed form

Comment: @James Could you perhaps explain a bit what’s causing those doubts? I spot checked the formula for numerical agreement with a couple of particular values like $(a,b)=(2,1)$ to see if there were any glaringly obvious problems, and everything seemed fine to me (at least so far…)

Comment: Maybe i am wrong,let me add my further work

Comment: i uploaded my proof

Comment: @James Have you checked if your final result actually differs from mine? The gamma duplication formula would be useful here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html

Comment: sorry i forgot to check

Answer (score 2):

$$\displaystyle{ = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\frac{{\ln \left( {\dfrac{{k + b}}{{k + a}}} \right)}}{{a - b}}} \right)}  = \frac{1}{{a - b}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\ln \left( {\frac{{k + b}}{{k + a}}} \right)} \right)} }$$ .
Nevertheless

$$\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\ln \left( {\frac{{k + b}}{{k + a}}} \right)} \right)}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2N} {\left( {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\ln \left( {\frac{{k + b}}{{k + a}}} \right)} \right)}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \ln \left( {\frac{{b\left( {1 + a} \right)\left( {2 + b} \right)..\left( {2N - 1 + a} \right)\left( {2N + b} \right)}}{{a\left( {1 + b} \right)\left( {2 + a} \right)..\left( {2N - 1 + b} \right)\left( {2N + a} \right)}}} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } \ln {P_n}}$$
And
$$\displaystyle{{P_N} = \frac{{b\left( {1 + a} \right)\left( {2 + b} \right)..\left( {2N - 1 + a} \right)\left( {2N + b} \right)}}{{a\left( {1 + b} \right)\left( {2 + a} \right)..\left( {2N - 1 + b} \right)\left( {2N + a} \right)}} = \frac{{\left( {{b^2}{{\left( {2 + b} \right)}^2}..{{\left( {2N + b} \right)}^2}} \right)\left( {a\left( {1 + a} \right)\left( {2 + a} \right)..\left( {2N - 1 + a} \right)\left( {2N + a} \right)} \right)}}{{\left( {{a^2}{{\left( {2 + a} \right)}^2}..{{\left( {2N + a} \right)}^2}} \right)\left( {b\left( {1 + b} \right)\left( {2 + b} \right)..\left( {2N - 1 + b} \right)\left( {2N + b} \right)} \right)}} = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = \frac{{{{\left( {\frac{b}{2}\left( {1 + \frac{b}{2}} \right)..\left( {N + \frac{b}{2}} \right)} \right)}^2}\left( {a\left( {1 + a} \right)\left( {2 + a} \right)..\left( {2N - 1 + a} \right)\left( {2N + a} \right)} \right)}}{{{{\left( {\frac{a}{2}\left( {1 + \frac{a}{2}} \right)..\left( {N + \frac{a}{2}} \right)} \right)}^2}\left( {b\left( {1 + b} \right)\left( {2 + b} \right)..\left( {2N - 1 + b} \right)\left( {2N + b} \right)} \right)}} = }$$

$$\displaystyle{\frac{{{N^b}{{\left( {\dfrac{{\left( {b/2} \right)\left( {1 + b/2} \right)..\left( {N + b/2} \right)}}{{{N^{b/2}}N!}}} \right)}^2}\left( {\dfrac{{a\left( {1 + a} \right)\left( {2 + a} \right)..\left( {2N - 1 + a} \right)\left( {2N + a} \right)}}{{{{\left( {2N} \right)}^a}\left( {2N} \right)!}}} \right){{\left( {2N} \right)}^a}}}{{{N^a}{{\left( {\dfrac{{\left( {a/2} \right)\left( {1 + a/2} \right)..\left( {N + a/2} \right)}}{{{N^{a/2}}N!}}} \right)}^2}\left( {\dfrac{{b\left( {1 + b} \right)\left( {2 + b} \right)..\left( {2N - 1 + b} \right)\left( {2N + b} \right)}}{{{{\left( {2N} \right)}^b}\left( {2N} \right)!}}} \right){{\left( {2N} \right)}^b}}}}$$
Taking the limit as N goes to infinity, we get:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} P_N = 2^{a-b} \frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{a}{2})}{\Gamma^2(\frac{b}{2})}$$

Then, we have:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^{a-1} y^{b-1}}{(1+xy)\ln (xy)} dx dy = \frac{1}{a-b}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \ln \left( \frac{k+b}{k+a} \right) + \ln 2 + \frac{1}{a-b}\ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{a}{2})}{\Gamma^2(\frac{b}{2})}\right)$$

If the numbers $\displaystyle{ a,b}$ are positive integers we would have a more elegant result